# Finish() ing duplicate activities

Tags: android, android-activity

If you have several activities onPause() is there a way to finish a specific activity?

edit: so for example, imagine on start activity 1 is called. Then activity 1 uses an intent to go to activity 2. then an update is made to the database and calls activity 1_new again so that it displays the updated database. At that point i want to get rid of the old activity 1.

Comment: Could you explain more of what you're trying to do?  Each activity's onPause will be invoked as it leaves the foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing here was calling startActivityForResult in the first activity. That way I was able to redisplay updated information from the second activity.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do. You'll need to look at the AndroidManifest.xml spec for activity calls stacks.

Specifically [android:launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

```
<activity android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

Careful though, launchModes are very tricky and can get you into trouble since it also depends on how the activity is launched from the Intent itself.

singleTop will essentially keep only 1 instance of that activity in the stack.

From [the Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode):

> If an instance of the activity already
> exists at the top of the target task,
> the system routes the intent to that
> instance through a call to its
> onNewIntent() method, rather than
> creating a new instance of the
> activity.

Comment: launch mode doesn't quite handle the case that I'm trying to solve. I'd like to refresh the activity that was old, not display the old activity.

Comment: Yes you can. You need to override onNewIntent() to perform the refresh of the activity.